# R counting appearance of a value across consecutive dates

Tags: r

I am trying to count the appearances of a value (across 2 columns) consecutively over the previous days. In the example this would be counting the consecutive days a team made an appearance (either in Hteam or Ateam) prior to that date. The aim would be to produce additional columns for both the home and away teams that showed these new values.

Test data:

```
data<- data.frame(
Date= c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-02", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-04", "2018-01-05"),
Hteam= c("A","D","B","A","C","A"),
Ateam= c("B","C","A","C","B","C"))


        Date Hteam Ateam
1 2018-01-01     A     B
2 2018-01-01     D     C
3 2018-01-02     B     A
4 2018-01-03     A     C
5 2018-01-04     C     B
6 2018-01-05     A     C
```

The aim would end up looking like:

```
         Date Hteam Ateam Hdays Adays
1 2018-01-01     A     B    0    0
2 2018-01-01     D     C    0    0
3 2018-01-02     B     A    1    1
4 2018-01-03     A     C    2    0
5 2018-01-04     C     B    1    0
6 2018-01-05     A     C    0    2
```

In my searching I haven't found an example close enough that I am able to adapt to this situation. I feel like I should be using a rollapply or dplyr grouping, but I can't get close to a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the following gives what you wanted assuming that `data` is sorted by `Date` and missing days are not considered.

```
t1 <- unique(unlist(data[-1]))
t2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(data[-1], data$Date), function(x) t1 %in% unlist(x)))
t3 <- apply(t2, 2, function(x) ave(x, cumsum(!x), FUN=cumsum))-1

data.frame(data
 , Hdays=t3[cbind(match(data$Date, rownames(t3)), match(data$Hteam, t1))]
 , Adays=t3[cbind(match(data$Date, rownames(t3)), match(data$Ateam, t1))])
#        Date Hteam Ateam Hdays Adays
#1 2018-01-01     A     B     0     0
#2 2018-01-01     D     C     0     0
#3 2018-01-02     B     A     1     1
#4 2018-01-03     A     C     2     0
#5 2018-01-04     C     B     1     0
#6 2018-01-05     A     C     0     2
```

Comment: Thank you, this does give exactly what I hoped with the test set. If I try apply this to the full data set I get the warning message "In split.default(x = seq_len(nrow(x)), f = f, drop = drop, ...) :  data length is not a multiple of split variable" after the line for t2. I think I need to learn the details of the code to understand where it might be going wrong. I would imagine it would have to be a data formatting issue?

Comment: How does your full data set look like?

Comment: It's a data table with 100's of observations of 84 variables, all numeric bar those listed in the table and "Result", which is also character. Dates are formatted as date (there is a day missing (24th Dec))  and there aren't any NAs in the date column (though there are elsewhere). Would the NAs cause the data length issue?

Comment: Maybe it's because you have a `data.table` and not a `data.frame`.

Comment: Yes, it is that exactly. You are a superstar, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your expected output is incorrect. Namely, row 5's `"C"` occurs twice above it, but has a `1`.

Here's a tidyverse version:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Date, rn), names_to = "x", values_to = "team") %>%
  mutate(x = gsub("team$", "", x)) %>%
  group_by(team) %>%
  mutate(days = row_number() - 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(c(Date, rn), names_from = x, values_from = c(team, days)) %>%
  select(-rn)
# # A tibble: 6 x 5
#   Date       team_H team_A days_H days_A
#   <chr>      <chr>  <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 2018-01-01 A      B           0      0
# 2 2018-01-01 D      C           0      0
# 3 2018-01-02 B      A           1      1
# 4 2018-01-03 A      C           2      1
# 5 2018-01-04 C      B           2      2
# 6 2018-01-05 A      C           3      3
```

Comment: You also need to load tidyr to pivot